# WEBMO-httpd.conf is empty where apache2.conf is not

Tags: apache, ubuntu, httpd.conf

I have installed Web MO on Ubuntu 12.04 , I successfully complete the step given in link [Web MO installation](http://www.webmo.net/support/installation.html)

But when I click on the URL specified at the end of setup process it shows as 404 NOT FOUND error

So I start configure the Apache Web Server
[Steps for configuring Web Server](http://www.webmo.net/support/fedoracore4.html#apache_conf)

as mentioned in web server configuration
cd /etc/httpd/conf not found in /etc folder

in /etc folder there exist an apache2.conf file and httpd.conf file , but httpd.conf file is empty where apache2.conf file is not.

I want to edit some lines in httpd.conf 
how can I do these , is there is any way to get contents in httpd.conf file

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: Are you aware about the differences between httpd and apache2? Because Ubuntu doesn't use httpd.

Comment: then how can I edit the details in httpd.conf file as given over here http://www.webmo.net/support/fedoracore4.html#apache_conf

Comment: Basically `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` is the same as `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` on Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for your Response @Fleuv but i need to edit   thses on httpd.conf file ., so from where I can make changes on it                       <IfModule mod_userdir.c> section
      Comment the line
            UserDir disable
      Uncomment the line
            UserDir public_html
      Uncomment the line
            AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
      Add the lines (to bottom of file)
            <Directory /home/*/public_html/cgi-bin>
            #Enable cgi scripts in user directories
            Options ExecCGI
            </Directory>http://www.webmo.net/support/fedoracore4.html#apache_conf

Answer (score 0):

To find your server config file. You can use the following command for `httpd`, `apaceh2` and `apachectl` (and maybe even more):

```
"apache name" -V | grep SERVER_CONFIG_FILE
```

so for `apache2` it will be

```
apache2 -V | grep SERVER_CONFIG_FILE
```

Comment: from where I get the  <IfModule mod_userdir.c> section ??

Comment: @121kk just add it anywhere in the file, of course not inside other statements. But also make sure the mod is installed and enabled to make it all work.

Comment: what all fields are comes under <ifModule mod_userdir.c> section

Comment: on running above commands it will shows                                      "  AH00526: Syntax error on line 74 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid Mutex directory in argument file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}  "

Comment: @121kk please describe what you did exactly and please provide (a snippet of) your config with the line numbers.

Comment: inorder to execute webmo on my system , need to configure the apache web server.... So as per http://www.webmo.net/support/fedoracore4.html#apache_conf in these link I needed to do all these. Now I successfully completed that task , but still it will shows 404 NOT FOUND error file not found error.... How can I resolve these problem